# how to delete elements? remove is not enough

Tags: jquery

How to delete DOM elements so they can't be found afterwards?

After removing elements they can still be found.. How can you avoid this?

this will still find removed elements

```
$(selector).attr('data-amount');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(selector).remove() will remove the element so that it cant be found[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

**UPDATE**

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.

Comment: thats the way I'm doing it.. but it's not enough

Comment: what do you mean its not enough, you must have cached it otherwise

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/5r3vx/1/ for an example of `remove` working as described.

Comment: my mistake.. found the bug :)

Comment: @clarkk: glad, that I was helpful and yeah you removed the down vote too, I think

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selected).removeAttr('data-amount');
```

If you want to remove $(selected) completely from the DOM tree, then

```
$(selected).remove();
```

Comment: isn't there an easier way to do it than removing each attribute etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that either:
1. your call to remove is removing nothing (double-check your $(selector) actually finds something)

1. your selector is a reference to a domNode, in which case you're newing up jQuery with a domNode, so that of course will work (domNodes don't need to be ON the document)
2. you did remove selector (because it was something like "a:first") but then "a:first" still works when you run it again because you have another one.